# Blur content behind div Mozilla mousewheel scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I want to re-make iOS 7 style blur header from this codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/zvcgx            //code bellow
```

Everything works fine in the Safari and Chrome (and, whitch surprised me, on Android and iOS devices).
But in Firefox a mousewheel doesn't work. Scroll works via scrollbar but not with a mousewheel.

This problem didn't appear just in my result (http://www.letsmind.cz), but also in original CodePen render.

I guess it's something caused with hiding the overflow, but I don't get how can it work in a Safari etc. but not just in a Mozilla.

Thank's for your time and answers if you could figure it out! :)

**EDIT: Touchbar scrolling is fine, even in Mozilla whitch is really really weird fact, cause it is the mouse wheel event, isn't it?**

HTML:

```
<div class="screen">

        <header>

            <div class="contOfHeader">

                <img src="">
                <ul>
                    <li>Vývoj</li>
                    <li>Grafika</li>
                    <li>Animace</li>
                    <li>Kreativní služby</li>
                    <li>Kontakt</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </header>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ol class="messages">

                    <li>

                        <div class="slider">
                        </div>

                        <p>Praesent porttitor nisl vel enim consectetur, vitae dictum ipsum condimentum.Praesent porttitor nisl vel enim consectetur, vitae dictum ipsum condimentum.</p>

                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

html {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",sans-serif;
    font-size:1rem;
}

html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

.screen {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:55px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#dedede;
    z-index:2;
    //box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);

    .contOfHeader{
        position: relative;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:1rem;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        line-height:55px;
        text-align:center;
        z-index: 2;
        font-weight:100;
        font-size: 17px;

        img{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        ul{
            display: inline-block;
            li{
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 70px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.content-blurred {
    //margin-top:45px;
    //padding:0 1rem;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    filter:blur(7px);
    opacity:.5;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-blurred .content {
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    //padding:0 1rem;
    z-index:1;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.content-wrapper .content {
    //margin-top:44px;
}

.content {
    display:block;
}

.messages {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.messages li {

}

.messages li:nth-child(even) {
    float:right;
}

.messages li:nth-child(even) img {
    float:right;
}

.messages li:nth-child(even) p {
    background:#158ffe;
    color:#fff;
}

.messages img {

}
```

JS:

```
    var content = document.querySelector('.content');
    var duplicate = content.cloneNode(true);
    var contentBlurred = document.createElement('div');
    contentBlurred.className = 'content-blurred';
    contentBlurred.appendChild(duplicate);

    var header = document.querySelector('header');
    header.appendChild(contentBlurred);

    var contentWrapper = document.querySelector('.content-wrapper'),
    translation;

    contentWrapper.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
      translation = 'translate3d(0,' + (-this.scrollTop + 'px') + ',0)';
      duplicate.style['-webkit-transform'] = translation;
      duplicate.style['-moz-transform'] = translation;
      duplicate.style['-ms-transform'] = translation;
      duplicate.style['transform'] = translation;

      console.log(duplicate);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with the biggest fortune, by adding this javascript into my code:

```
var isMouseScroll = false;

window.addEventListener('wheel',function(e)
{
  console.log('mouse wheel');
  isMouseScroll = true;
});

window.addEventListener('scroll',function(e)
{
  if(!isMouseScroll) {
    console.log('scroll');
  }

  isMouseScroll = false;
});
```

It somehow "unlocks" the mouse wheel. Dunno why, dunno how, but it works.

And the problem in Firefox is (by my thought) that when html, body{overflow:hidden;}, then when you allow to scroll div inside, it won't trigger by scrolling on the mouse (but scrollbar and touchpad are working fine).

Thank's for your time, still it's bugged, but I know how to evade it.